# R Shiny dateInputRange function breaks histogram

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make a histogram react to the dateInputRange function. I had the my app working already with just an age slider outputting to the histogram, and a table of the results below the histgram also. I added dateInputRange to my code, and filtered the output by the column in my source data that I want to filter on (based on the date), and the app still launches, but the histogram no longer plots. The renderTable still reacts to the slider input, but for the histogram I just get a blank grey plot.

When I launch the app, the console gives me this message:

*"Warning in `==.default`(c("10/11/2016", "10/16/2016", "11/22/2016", "11/21/2016",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"*

Code is below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(


   titlePanel("ED Admissions"),


   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("AgeInput","Age",min = 3, max = 125, c(3,65)),

         dateRangeInput("DateInput", "Date")
          ),


      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("AgePlot"),
         br(), br(),
         tableOutput("ClientTable")


      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$AgePlot <- renderPlot({
    filtered <-
    edadmits %>%
      ##filtering is by variables in the dataset
      filter(Client_AGE >= input$AgeInput[1],
             Client_AGE <= input$AgeInput[2],
             Discharge_Claim_Start_Date == input$DateInput
             )

    ggplot(filtered, aes(Client_AGE))+
      geom_histogram()
  })

  output$ClientTable <- renderTable({
    filtered <-
      edadmits %>%

      filter(Client_AGE >= input$AgeInput[1],
             Client_AGE <= input$AgeInput[2])

    filtered
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Name <- c("Person 1","Person 2","Person 3","Person 4","Person 5","Person 6","Person 7","Person 8",
            "Person 9","Person 10","Person 11","Person 12", "Person 13","Person 14","Person 15",
          "Person 16","Person 17","Person 18","Person 19","Person 20")

Diagnosis <- sample(1:10, 20, replace=TRUE)

Discharge.Date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2016/12/01'), as.Date('2016/12/31'), by="day"), 20)

Age <- sample(1:125, 20)

edadmits <- data.frame(Name, Diagnosis, Discharge.Date, Age)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("ED Admissions, 12.1.16-12.31.16"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("AgeInput","Age",min = 3, max = 125, c(3,65)),

      dateRangeInput("DateInput", "Date", start= "2016-12-01", end= "2016-12-31", 
                     min= "2016-12-01", max = "2016-12-31")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("AgePlot"),
      br(), br(),
      tableOutput("ClientTable")


    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$AgePlot <- renderPlot({
    filtered <-
      edadmits %>%
      ##filtering is by variables in the dataset
      filter(Age >= input$AgeInput[1],
             Age <= input$AgeInput[2],
             Discharge.Date >= input$DateInput[1],
             Discharge.Date <= input$DateInput[2]
      )

    ggplot(filtered, aes(Age))+
      geom_histogram()
  })

  output$ClientTable <- renderTable({
    filtered <-
      edadmits %>%
      ##filtering is by variables in the dataset
      filter(Age >= input$AgeInput[1],
             Age <= input$AgeInput[2],
             Discharge.Date >= input$DateInput[1],
             Discharge.Date <= input$DateInput[2])

    filtered
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Replace `Discharge_Claim_Start_Date == input$DateInput` with `Discharge_Claim_Start_Date>= input$DateInput[1],Discharge_Claim_Start_Date<= input$DateInput[2]`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work, the plot is still not rendering at all.

Comment: The error message in the console did go away with your suggested change, but the app's behavior was the same. Will work on a reproducible example.

Comment: So, in the process of creating a reproducible example, I got the dateInput box to work with my dummy data, but it still won't work with my real data. Perhaps something to do with how the data is being read into R in my original? OP edited to show reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might come from a problem with dates, so try reformating them using `strftime()`. Also to simplify your code, you can use `reactive` like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    edadmits %>%
      filter(Age >= input$AgeInput[1],
             Age <= input$AgeInput[2],
             Discharge.Date >= input$DateInput[1],
             Discharge.Date <= input$DateInput[2]) %>%
      mutate(Discharge.Date=strftime(Discharge.Date, "%Y/%m/%d"))
  })

  output$AgePlot <- renderPlot(ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(Age))+geom_histogram())

  output$ClientTable <- renderTable(filtered_data())
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does look like the dates are the culprit somehow. They are getting read in as "character", although from what I can tell that should be okay for dateRangeInput. Will look into reformatting, I'm pretty new to this and couldn't get that to work this afternoon, but I think it's beyond the scope of this question.